# How can we access req and res inside use middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have this passport.js middleware :

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.host + "/google-login/callback"
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // here I need the req and res
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

As you see i need to access the req and res just before done..

How can I do this?

Here is the whole code if you want to look at my google login module:

```
router.use(passport.initialize());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: config.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.host + "/google-login/callback"
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // here I want to access req and res
        return done(null, userInfo.name);
    }
));

router.get('/', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/signup' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/google-login/popup');
    });

router.get('/popup', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('login/popup-close');
});

router.get('/popup-done', (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/accounts/' + req.query.redirect);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This portion only defines a *strategy*, i.e it usually returns a callback object, in your code its `userInfo`

```
    clientID: config.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.host + "/google-login/callback"
    }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // here I want to access req and res
        return done(null, userInfo.name);
    }
));
```

This portion returns the req,res object that you are using, e.g:

```
   (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/google-login/popup');
    });
```

Ideally, you should just let the strategy just respond with a pure response of the Google auth and then use the object in conjunction with the `req,res` objects in your `router.get` parts of the code.

You will not get the `req,res` because the above just defines an internal passport strategy and returns a object - it would be part of your request, i.e `router.get` blocks.

Comment: The only reason I want the `req` and `res` in that place is that I want to access them along with `userInfo` Now I should find a solution to pass `userInfo` to where I have access to req and res But How?

Comment: Have you reviewed http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ - It utilizes your strategy and then gives you a `req,res` object and the result of the auth as another object, e.g: `user`